# Using Proguard with Kotlin server

Tags: kotlin, gradle, proguard

I can't configure Proguard for pure Kotlin app (no Android). Used code from their site:

```
tasks.register<ProGuardTask>("proguard") {
    configuration("proguard-rules.pro")

    injars(tasks.named<Jar>("jar").flatMap { it.archiveFile })

    // Automatically handle the Java version of this build.
    if (System.getProperty("java.version").startsWith("1.")) {
        // Before Java 9, the runtime classes were packaged in a single jar file.
        libraryjars("${System.getProperty("java.home")}/lib/rt.jar")
    } else {
        // As of Java 9, the runtime classes are packaged in modular jmod files.
        libraryjars(
            mapOf("jarfilter" to "!**.jar", "filter" to "!module-info.class"),
            "${System.getProperty("java.home")}/jmods/java.base.jmod"
        )
        //libraryjars "${System.getProperty('java.home')}/jmods/....."
    }

    verbose()

    val baseCoordinates = "my-kserver" // Provide the appropriate value for baseCoordinates
    outjars(layout.buildDirectory.file("libs/${baseCoordinates}-minified.jar"))
}

// keep this if you want run proguard task automatically after building
tasks.build.get().finalizedBy(tasks.getByName("proguard"))
```

But it doesn’t work: I have warnings that every class is missed. Also not sure what `baseCoordinates` is.

Comment: Why would you want to use proguard on a server-application in the first place?

Comment: I think to launch the .jar with a public CI/CD like cloud functions.